# How to split a data frame by factor then merge by an ID variable

Tags: r, merge, split, do.call

So I have a data frame with two vectors. Time and team.

```
df <- data.frame(time=rep(seq(1:3),3), team=LETTERS[rep(1:3,each=3)])

>  time team
>1    1    A
>2    2    A
>3    3    A
>4    1    B
>5    2    B
>6    3    B
>7    1    C
>8    2    C
>9    3    C
```

How do I split the data.frame by time then merge it back together by time? Something like this.

```
>  time df.A df.B df.C
>1    1    A    B    C
>2    2    A    B    C
>3    3    A    B    C
```

I figured out how to split the data.frame using split or dlply but I haven't had any success using a cbind or merge to get the data frame back together.

Also, the lengths of each (split) list are different so any help adding NA into the mix will also be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your intended output isn't possible from your input because `time` and `team` are perfectly colinear.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Just updated the input df to reflect the change.

Comment: You need to update the code, as well.

Comment: @Richard from `library(reshape2)`, `dcast(df, time ~ team)`. Isn't useful?

Comment: Just did. @Paulo, I'll give that a try....

Comment: Thanks Paulo, tried and successfully used dcast, wasn't able to figure out a way to apply it to a data frame with a lot of variables. I used '+' but didn't know how to apply a more quick method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reshape` for this:

```
> df$tmp <- df$team
> reshape(df, idvar='time', timevar='team', direction='wide')
  time tmp.A tmp.B tmp.C
1    1     A     B     C
2    2     A     B     C
3    3     A     B     C
```